# Unable to push to heroku

Tags: heroku

Trying to push to heroku.

When I type: heroku create

getting this message.

!    No account specified.
 !
 !    Run this command with --account 
 !
 !    You can also add it as a git config attribute with:
 !      git config heroku.account work

Using Rails 3.1.1

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you've installed the Heroku Accounts plugin which allows you switch between multiple heroku accounts - follow the instructions here https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts to add an account for it to use

Answer (score 1):

type in `gem install heroku`

Then upload rsa key of github to heroku

```
$ heroku keys:add
Uploading ssh public key /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Once you key in configured with heroku and github with command all your code goes to github and from there to Heroku

```
git push heroku master
```

and soon you will see these messages

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
```